# How to get value from an HTML form and assing it to a global variable in JS?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, variables, getelementbyid

I am new to JavaScript and I am trying to write my first simple app. I would like to have a code fragment which gets the value from an HTML text form and then assigns that value to a global variable. What I've got so far in HTML:

```
Type something: <input type="text" id="user_text">

<input type="button" onclick="getText()" value="Submit">
```

and in JS:

```
function getText()
    {
        var click_value = document.getElementById("user_text").value;
        return(click_value);
    }
```

Is there a way to assign the value returned by the getText function to a global variable (so that I could later on use it in other functions)?

Comment: If you want to assign to global variable, just don't use the var in front of the assignment, like this : global_click = document.getElementById("user_text").value; (you need to define var global_click outside the function to make it global)

Comment: you can already use the value from anywhere as _user_text.value_

Comment: I like how the return statement looks like a function call in your code :)

Answer (score 1):

`var globalVar;`

`...`

`function(){
    globalVar = document.getElementById('user_text').value;
}`

Define the global variable outside the scope of the function, then set it inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

You should change `click_value` to `window.click_value`. This makes it available within the whole 'window' (webpage).